Database Error in Elementor/WP Rentals Wordpress install
when I turn on display debug I see the following error shown below
WordPress database error: [Table '5dmzaa_e_events' already exists]
CREATE TABLE 5DMZAA_e_events ( id bigint(20) unsigned auto_increment primary key, event_data text null, created_at datetime not null ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
WordPress database error: [Duplicate key name 'created_at_index']
ALTER TABLE 5DMZAA_e_events ADD INDEX created_at_index (created_at)
any ideas whats causing it?
Wordpress with Elementor running WP Rentals Theme
